# Duplicate KeyPair with a DynamoDb batchLoad causes error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

When I am performing a batchLoad I'm getting an error which states: "provided list of item keys contains duplicates" which I could understand as the List I am passing to batchLoad might have duplicates with same hash key and range key.

I understand batchWrite does throw this exception, is batchLoad also designed the same way? Is there any option to say that if given KeyPair is already queried then drop this KeyPair during batchLoad? Or should the callee ensure that KeyPair list has only unique items? The batchLoad takes a List of KeyPair.

I couldn't find any post/blog on this and couldn't find explanation on this behaviour in the [AWS documentation either](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#batchLoad-java.lang.Iterable-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-).
I am using the AWS SDK for Java.
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the documentation could do with tightening up. I would raise this with AWS if you can be bothered. BTW, batchLoad takes any iterable object, not just List. Presumably you would be better off with a Set here?

Comment: I would probably use Set for my usecase and stick with it for batch use cases. As any iterable was accepted I ended up using a List. Thanks !

Comment: On the bottom right of each documentation page is a "Feedback" button. Please provide this in a feedback otherwise things will not get better. On the back end it creates a ticket which gets looked at and tracked.

Comment: @Kirk Done, submitted a feedback.